# Issues with two fact tables that share one dimension

Tags: architecture, ssas

I have an issue with two fact tables connected to one date dimension. The two fact tables have ranges of different dates, but all dates are present in the date dimension.

I encounter the problem when I try to process the cube, I get an error stating that my date dimension does not have a FK for dates that I know are in the dimension. See the illustration below:

[image]

Only when my two fact tables share the same date ranges will my cube process. If either cube has any dates that are not in the other, then the process fails.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Doing web searches, I came across the term "Conformed Dimensions", but still researching how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit causing the cube process to fail. There was a filter applied to the date dimension in the DSV that I had fogotten about. Removed the filter and the cube processed with no issue.

That was a painful reminder of keeping trouble shooting simple.